# Brother MFC-J430W printer receiving data, but not printing anything

Tags: drivers, printing

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm trying to get a Brother MFC-J430W printer to work. I downloaded and installed Driver Install Tool from [Brother's website](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj430w_all&os=127). I unzipped it and followed the instructions on the [instructions page](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj430w_all&os=127&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625) with

```
sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
MFC-J430W
```

it worked, and my computer sees the printer. But when I try to print, I can see on the printer's screen that it says "Receiving Data" but then it stops and goes back to its default screen. When I go to Ubuntu's printer menu and click "Show completed jobs" it shows everything I've tried to print.

Brother's install page says I should expect a prompt that says

```
Will you specify the DeviceURI ?
```

but instead I got a list of 16 choices and a prompt that said

```
select the number of destination Device URI.
```

And I chose 16, which was something like

```
usb://Brother/MFC-J430W?serial=BROD3F970004
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work by removing all the whitespace from the path leading to the file, for example:

```
/media/User/Data/Downloads/favorite folder/look at the spaces/linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
```

became

```
/media/User/Data/Downloads/favoritefolder/lookatthespaces/linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
```

and then following the installation instructions

Comment: great that you got this resolved after 2 months!